# restoring symlinks for transferred cygwin system

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, tar, busybox

I backed up a portable cygwin installation the old way: in a simple tarball with `tar -cvf cygwin`; then I tried to restore it on a portable hard drive the old way: with a simple `tar -xvf cygwin`. The backup worked, but all the symlinks were broken. How do I restore them properly?

Comment: Did you use a Cygwin `tar` or a native Windows `tar`?

Comment: The cygwin one; I'm trying the BusyBox-w32 one too.

Comment: If you `tar -tvvf` the archive, does it appear to contain symlinks?

Comment: however, some softlinks (`cygwin64/cygwin/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map -> pdftex_ndl14.map` for instance) seem to be operational.

Comment: perhaps I need to rerun the post-installation scripts, but I don't know where to look for...

Comment: Wait, how do you get "operation not permitted" out of a command that's only supposed to _list_ the archive?

Comment: messed up: `-xvvf` instead of `-tvvf`...

Comment: and there are hard and soft links in the tarball...